# Remove some of the items from the Style drop down

Tags: ckeditor4.x

I have added the advanced tool bar and in the toolbar groups
added {name:'styles'}

When i add the styles by default it adds two buttons Styles and Format

How do i remove some of the items from Styles ?

For eg : Styles currently has block styles like 'Italic title', 'Subtitle', etc and Inline styles like 'Marker', 'Big', 'Typewriter' etc

I want to retain the styles but want to delete just couple of elements from the dropdown eg : 'Marker' , 'Subtitle'

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This [link](http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/Remove-item-style-list) has a similar question.

**Edit:**

This code block is the extract of what you need to add before initialing CKEditor.

```
CKEDITOR.addStylesSet( 'mystyleslist',
[
    /* Inline Styles */

   { name : 'readMore', element : 'span', attributes : { 'class' : 'readMore' } },
   { name : 'BoldItal' , element : 'span', styles:
      {
      'font-weight' :   'bold',
      'font-style' :      'italic'
      }
   },

   /* Object Styles */

   {name : 'Image on Left', element : 'img',
      attributes :
      {
      'style' : 'padding: 5px; margin-right: 5px',
      'border' : '2',
      'align' : 'left'
      }
   },

   {name : 'Image on Right', element : 'img',
      attributes :
      {
      'style' : 'padding: 5px; margin-left: 5px',
      'border' : '2',
      'align' : 'right'
      }
   }
]);

CKEDITOR.config.stylesCombo_stylesSet = 'mystyleslist';
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Please have a look At [answer]. Answers with Just a mere link are not encouraged

Comment: But i noticed that i don't have  a plugin for style ie .Styles Combo as mentioned in the link . Does it mean i need to install it and then disable it . Currently i notice that the 'Styles' items comes with out any additional plugins.

Comment: Just try to add these lines before you initialize. That should work I guess.

Comment: Styles is a default plugin which is added to the source ckeditor.js direcrly on building the ckeditor package